# Decompressing a gzip data stream in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, gzip, zlib

Is there a simple, standard way to decompress a gzip raw data buffer in Objective-C? I could not find anything useful in the Apple Developer documentation.

If not, can you point me to a code walk-through, a library, anything that will make my life easier? I am not afraid to write C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a NSData category available at cocoadev that can handle zlib and gzip data:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory

If you just need gzip decompression, you can remove the zlib & hash related methods.
Don't forget to add a link libz.dylib (OS X standard library) build phase.

**Update**
As pointed out by marcos1490 in the comments, the original CocoaDev entry disappeared, but someone extended that NSData category and wrote about it: http://deusty.blogspot.de/2007/07/gzip-compressiondecompression.html

Comment: The URL is no longer valid.

Comment: The new URL to deusty isn't valid any more, either. A more persistent one would be here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP -- However, none of these meet the question's title - I was seeking a true *stream* but these all only work on NSData and are not made for large files, to be read in chunks from a file. A true streaming solution example is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_and_decompressing_files_with_stream_compression

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) for decompression. I've tried compressing files using it, hope the other would work perfectly.

Here is the code snippet

```
ZipArchive *zip = [ZipArchive alloc];
[zip UnzipOpenFile:Zip-File-Path];
[zip UnzipFileTo:Unzip-Folder-Path overWrite:As-You-Wish];
```

Also include libz.dylib in build phase.