# xcode & (un)zip file

Tags: ios7, xcode5, unzip

I have an problem, I have develop one app where I actually need to unzip file. This files I receive from internet, save on Document folder of device and try to unzip.
But... unzip never occurs. The message I receive is:
Error Domain=SSZipArchiveErrorDomain Code=-1 "failed to open zip file" UserInfo=0xad36430 {NSLocalizedDescription=failed to open zip file}

Also I tried other library... but the result is the same.

The zip file is made by server (so we have no control over this part.) but we know that they use gzip to create this file.

I have already used "search"... but with no luck.
One more important note. If I unzip this file on my mac, than zip it again and point "localFilePath" to this new file, all works fine!. Also, the server guy say that they use this ZIP in other apps with no problems at all.

Any advice where do I need to look?

Thanks

The code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://......"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *localFilePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePath lastPathComponent]];
    NSString *unzipFolder = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/unzipfolder"];

    NSLog(@"localFilePath: %@",localFilePath);
    NSLog(@"unzip folder: %@",unzipFolder);

    NSError *erro = nil;
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:localFilePath toDestination:unzipFolder overwrite:YES password:nil error:&erro delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Erro: %@",erro);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: gzip is not zip. Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172734/decompressing-a-gzip-data-stream-in-objective-c

Comment: and how do you ungzip file ? :)
any advise ?
I have looked at http://github.com/st3fan/cocoa-utils/blob/master/src/NSDataGZipAdditions.m

Comment: (btw, to see how it works, the command line tool is called `gunzip`, not "ungzip" :) )